# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/Panel' in 'F:\CFC\aaa\src\components\Login'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I fix this issue?

After compiling this error shows:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/Panel' in
>   'F:\CFC\aaa\src\components\Login'

Comment: did you do `npm install react-bootstrap --save`?

Comment: Make sure this module is installed linked correctly. `npm link [module-name]`

Comment: npm install react-bootstrap --save      yes i did this but not working

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: Where is the error coming from? TypeScript? Webpack? Please provide more info !

Answer (score 3):

npm install --save bootstrap  react-bootstrap

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the react-bootstrap documentation when migrating to Bootstrap 4, [Panel was replaced by Card](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/migrating/#panel).

For me, the [Accordion component from Bootstrap 5.](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/#rb-docs-content) was more suited to what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would like also to guess your issue.
react-bootstrap package has a Panel component only until v0.33.1 version - later versions does not have such component. So make sure you installed correct version like `npm i -S react-bootstrap@0.33.1`

Also another problem could be also the reason in later versions
Instead of importing default like

```js
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

I would suggest you try

```js
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```